# How to set message for error reponse status in Spring MVC?

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-mvc

I have a spring mvc handler like this:

```kotlin
    @PostMapping("jwtToken")
    fun jwtToken(@RequestBody body: JWTToken)
    {
        val token = body.token
        if(token.isNullOrBlank())
            throw ResponseStatusException(HttpStatus.UNAUTHORIZED, "Empty token")

    }
```

If i send it an incorrect input, that triggers the exception, i get a reponse body like this:

```json
{
  "timestamp": "2020-10-30T03:41:20.305+00:00",
  "status": 401,
  "error": "Unauthorized",
  "message": "",
  "path": "/auth/jwtToken"
}
```

Why is the 'message' field empty in the response when i did assign a message to the exception? How do i set the message field

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It might be related to the updated behaviour of the Spring Boot.

https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/wiki/Spring-Boot-2.3-Release-Notes#changes-to-the-default-error-pages-content

```
server.error.include-message=always
```

in .properties should do the trick but I prefer to use my own extended classes like this:

```
class CustomException(message: String): Exception(message) { ... }
```